# Determining text width

Tags: c#, java

I want to find correct approach for calculating text width for specified font in C#.
I have following approach in Java and it seems it works:

```
public static float textWidth(String text, Font font) {

    // define context used for determining glyph metrics.        
    BufferedImage bufImage = new BufferedImage(2 /* dummy */, 2 /* dummy */, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bufImage.createGraphics();
    FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = g2d.getFontRenderContext();

    // determine width
    Rectangle2D bounds = font.createGlyphVector(fontRenderContext, text).getLogicalBounds();
    return (float) bounds.getWidth();
}
```

But watch my code in C#:

```
public static float TextWidth(string text, Font f)
{
    // define context used for determining glyph metrics.        
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    // determine width         
    SizeF bounds = grfx.MeasureString(text, f);
    return bounds.Width;
}
```

I have different values for above two functions for the same font. Why? And what is correct approach in my case?

**UPDATE**: The **TextRenderer.MeasureText** approach gives only **integer** measurements. I need more precuse result.

Comment: Java & ".Net" ( c#, VB.NET, else ) use different libraries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `TextRenderer`

```
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText( < with 6 overloads> );

TextRenderer.DrawText( < with 8 overloads> );
```

---

There is a good article on `TextRenderer` in [this MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc751527.aspx).

Comment: +1 and in Java a better approach would be to use FontMetrics to determine the width of a a String with the stringWidth() function.

Comment: Probably the three approaches (FontRenderContext, MeasureString, and TextRenderer) do not only yield different widths but also render the text slightly differently. However the measurements are most probably consistent with the corresponding render methods. I would say that the right method is to use the same technique for measuring and rendering.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing stands out, other than lack of disposing your objects:

```
public static float TextWidth(string text, Font f) {
  float textWidth = 0;

  using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1,1))
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
    textWidth = g.MeasureString(text, f).Width;
  }

  return textWidth;
}
```

The other method to try is the `TextRenderer` class:

```
return TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, f).Width;
```

but it returns an int, not a float.