# Create a circle avatar image in .net

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I want to create a default avatar image which is a circle with initials in it. I want to do this on the server side as a png. Is this possible using the .net graphics library?

Comment: There is no single ".NET graphics library", there are several. For example, [`System.Drawing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`System.Windows.Media`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used largely independently of each other.

Comment: I had only seen system.drawing but will look into system.windows.media.

Comment: Of course. Create a Bitmap, draw/fill a Circle, maybe measure the string putput to place it nicely, then drawString the letters, save as Fileformat.Png. 5-10 lines.

Comment: Does "on the server side" mean you are using ASP.NET?

Comment: The answer to your question is quite simply "yes". Maybe you need to be more specific?

Comment: Visit this link for helpful information about this topic [Create text avatar image (Rectangle and Circle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120224/set-default-user-profile-picture-to-an-image-of-their-initials/35326880#35326880)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up doing this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction TaW

```
public ActionResult Avatar()
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(50, 50))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#eeeeee")))
                    {

                        g.FillEllipse(b, 0, 0, 49, 49);
                    }

                    float emSize = 12;
                    g.DrawString("AM", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, emSize, FontStyle.Regular),
                        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 15);
                }

                using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    var result = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Characters with a small width are not centered for example AI. I added this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722368/determining-text-width but switched to a CSS solution in the end.