# Picture profile generator c# usings

Tags: c#, image, profile, using, avatar

I'm trying to follow this model ([Set default user profile picture to an image of their initials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120224/set-default-user-profile-picture-to-an-image-of-their-initials/48190659#48190659)) but my solution doesn't recognize these [usings]:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
```

I want to apply this in my xamarin forms project but I also tried on a simple PLC NET Framework but the error is the same. Can you help me?

Note: I use the same solution with 2 projects - 1 xamarin forms and other PLC Net Framework.

Comment: Did you add the references? Keep in mind that a namespace can be spanned across multiple assemblies

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.
Please never post screen shots of text as they are not searchable. Instead add them to your question formatted as code

Comment: @Alex yes, the problem is these using:
[code]using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;[code]

Aren't recognized and I don't understand why

Comment: @Spangen, Ok, sorry this mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around: you can use [SkiaSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/) for drawing image.